# Where is the "resend" option?

Tags: gmail

Sometimes one wants to resend an email for various reasons - I am only finding reply/reply all/forward.  Where is the resend?

Answer (score 4):

There is no *resend* option. There is one alternative to your problem. You can forward the email and send it to the same person.

Emails were not implemented a resend option compared to smartphones because all emails get sent to the receiving email address. If an email address is invalid, the email will still go through, but the hosting provider will send you an email stating that it was not sent because the email address you are sending that email to is invalid.

Comment: Not all email providers will send "bounce" messages.

Comment: @AlE. Can you give me examples of these companies? I would love to do more research on them.

Comment: Not offhand, no. I just know that I've sent plenty of messages to non-existent mailboxes and never got a bounce message. I also know that that's a configuration set by the receiving email server.

Comment: For various reasons there could be a delivery failure that will not reproduce when you resend. E.g. one of the mail server en-route to delivery was misconfigured to report a permanent delivery failure and since the last attempt got fixed. I think not having an authentic Resend in Gmail is a mis-feature.